# Down Casting to indirect subclass does not work?

Tags: java, inheritance, casting, multiple-inheritance, downcast

```
        public class A
    {

      public void printA(){
        System.out.println("A");  
      }

    }


    public class B extends A
    {
       public void printB(){
        System.out.println("B");  
      }

    }

    public class C extends B
    {
       public void printC(){
        System.out.println("C");  
      }

    }

    public class test {
        public static void main(String[] args)
      {

     A  a = new B();
          a.printA(); // work

        B b = (B) a;
          b.printB(); // work

          C c = (C) b;
          c.printC(); // not work throw  java.lang.ClassCastException

      }
}
```

i have three classes A and B and C 
C extends from B and B extends from A 
why down casting work from A to B, and does not work from B to C ,although the relation between them like A and B , B is parent of C so how it work JVM??

Comment: You can't change the class of an Object, you can only change the class of a reference.

Comment: i don't understand where i'm trying to change class of object in my code??

Comment: When you do `(C) b` you are trying to pretend this changes the type of the object to a `C` but it doesn't. The type of the Object is always a `B`.

Comment: but B is parent of C it's true ? so C is instanceof B and can i do casting!!

Comment: This is explained in many places in the internet already. In all respect for stackoverflowers, I doubt that anything that will be written in this thread will be clearer than what is already out there. Please do your research and study the resources.

Comment: This is the way you want it to be in object-oriented programming. If A is plant, B is tree and C is oak tree, you have created a tree, and it can be held in a variable of type plant (because a tree is a plant) and in a tree variable (obviously), and it can be assigned back and forth between those two varables. It cannot be held in a variable of type oak tree because it is not an oak tree.

Comment: @AndroidAL-Khatib a B object is not an instance of a C so you can't cast it to C because B is not a C.

Comment: I would expect you get the `ClassCastException` already when you do the cast, that is in the line `C c = (C) b;`, and even without calling `printC()`. Isn’t this the case? Your stack trace should tell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Classes can only be cast to their parent classes, they have no knowledge about their subclasses.

Since your object is an instance of `B`, it does not implement methods of `C`.

This will work:

```
  A  a = new C();
  a.printA(); // work

  B b = (B) a;
  b.printB(); // work

  C c = (C) b;
  c.printC(); // work
```

Comment: You can cast class only to it's parent, but not to it's child. Because class doesn't know anything about sublasses.